# Objective-C @autoreleasepool and method with "alloc" in the name

Tags: objective-c

My friends and I were trying to figure out when `@autoreleasepool` is useful with `ARC` enabled and we've noticed strange behavior in the application. We've created multiple methods:

```
- (NSDictionary *)autoreleaseDict {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"object", @"key", nil];
}

- (NSDictionary *)regularDict {
    return [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"object",@"key", nil];
}

- (NSDictionary *)allocDict {
    return [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"object", @"key", nil];
}

- (NSDictionary *)allocAutoreleaseDict {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"object", @"key", nil];
}
```

and ran them in the 2 nested loops:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
                NSDictionary *dict = [self autoreleaseDict];
//                NSDictionary *dict = [self regularDict];
//                NSDictionary *dict = [self allocDict];
//                NSDictionary *dict = [self allocAutoreleaseDict];
            }
        }
    }
```

and the same methods with different names showed different results (`regularDict` and `allocDict`):

**Test1 (`autoreleaseDict`)**
[image]

**Test2 (`regularDict`)**
[image]

**Test3 (`allocDict`)**
[image]

**Test4 (`allocAutoreleaseDict`)**
[image]

AFAIK with `ARC` when method returns object, this object is `autorelease`. That is true for Test1, Test2 and Test4, but it seems to me, that in Test3 (`allocDict`) object is not `autorelease`, because of low memory usage. And I believe that is because of `alloc` word in the name of this method.

Maybe somebody knows why application works like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the [basic memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) of iOS says: "You own any object you create.
You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”".
This means, if an object uses your methods that begin with "alloc", this object is not autoreleased, but retained by the object that called the method. The compiler does however insert release messages appropriately, so that the object will be released when no longer needed.
So there is indeed a fundamental difference between your methods, depending on the name used.

Comment: Thanx, I forget about this article.
Is it a good idea to create methods with `alloc` in the name?
EDIT:
I mean, is it a good practice, to use method with `alloc` in the name to retain the object, that is returned from this method?

Comment: I guess in most cases it makes no difference, since ARC cares automatically about retain, release, and autorelease. It may make a difference if you allocate many objects so that you are in danger of low memory, or if you put many objects into an autorelease pool that is drained very rarely (but in this case you may define your own autorelease pools that are drained more often).